# Generar Codigo QR con información de la Base de Datos

Tags: php, mysql, qrcode, qr

Estoy intentando hacer un ***sistema*** que me permita agilizar el acceso a un evento mediante la lectura de **Código QR** he estado investigando acerca de eso pero no he encontrado mucho. ¿Alguien tiene experiencia sobre el tema?

Que sea muy básico, debe consultar la información de la base de datos y la muestre al leer el código QR.

Esto es lo que llevo hasta el momento de tutoriales, etc. ¿Se pudiera que en vez de escribir la información se consulte de la base de datos?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el codigo

```
<?php    

//set it to writable location, a place for temp generated PNG files
$PNG_TEMP_DIR = dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'temp'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;

//html PNG location prefix
$PNG_WEB_DIR = 'temp/';

include "qrlib.php";    

//ofcourse we need rights to create temp dir
if (!file_exists($PNG_TEMP_DIR))
    mkdir($PNG_TEMP_DIR);


$filename = $PNG_TEMP_DIR.'test.png';

//processing form input
//remember to sanitize user input in real-life solution !!!
$errorCorrectionLevel = 'L';
if (isset($_REQUEST['level']) && in_array($_REQUEST['level'], array('L','M','Q','H')))
    $errorCorrectionLevel = $_REQUEST['level'];    

$matrixPointSize = 4;
if (isset($_REQUEST['size']))
    $matrixPointSize = min(max((int)$_REQUEST['size'], 1), 10);


if (isset($_REQUEST['data'])) { 

    //it's very important!
    if (trim($_REQUEST['data']) == '')
        die('data cannot be empty! <a href="?">back</a>');

    // user data
    $filename = $PNG_TEMP_DIR.'test'.md5($_REQUEST['data'].'|'.$errorCorrectionLevel.'|'.$matrixPointSize).'.png';
    QRcode::png($_REQUEST['data'], $filename, $errorCorrectionLevel, $matrixPointSize, 2);    

}    

//display generated file
echo '<img src="'.$PNG_WEB_DIR.basename($filename).'" />';  

//config form
echo '<form action="index.php" method="post">
    DATOS:&nbsp;<input name="data" value="'.(isset($_REQUEST['data'])?htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['data']):'PHP QR Code :)').'" />&nbsp;
    CALIDAD:&nbsp;<select name="level">
        <option value="L"'.(($errorCorrectionLevel=='L')?' selected':'').'>Baja</option>
        <option value="M"'.(($errorCorrectionLevel=='M')?' selected':'').'>Media</option>
        <option value="Q"'.(($errorCorrectionLevel=='Q')?' selected':'').'>Moderada</option>
        <option value="H"'.(($errorCorrectionLevel=='H')?' selected':'').'>Alta</option>
    </select>&nbsp;
    TAMAÑO:&nbsp;<select name="size">';

for($i=1;$i<=10;$i++)
    echo '<option value="'.$i.'"'.(($matrixPointSize==$i)?' selected':'').'>'.$i.'</option>';

echo '</select>&nbsp;
    <input type="submit" value="GENERAR"></form>';
```

Answer (score 1):

esta facil, yo tengo uno hecho, mi codigo para generar es:

```
    //creamos el codigo QR
    $dir = '../../qr/ordenes_trabajo/';
    //Si no existe la carpeta la creamos
    if (!file_exists($dir)){
     mkdir($dir);
    }
    //Declaramos la ruta y nombre del archivo a generar
    $imagen = $folioCompleto.'.png';
    $filename = $dir.$imagen;

    //Parametros de Configuración

    $tamaño = 2; //Tamaño de Pixel
    $level = 'L'; //Precisión Baja
    $framSize = 3; //Tamaño en blanco
    $folioCompleto; //Texto

    //Enviamos los parametros a la Función para generar código QR 
    QRcode::png($folioCompleto, $filename, $level, $tamaño, $framSize);
```

en mi caso, la variable $folioCompleto es lo que me traigo de la BD con una consulta hecha previamente

```
    $result = $modOrdenT->ultimofolio();
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    $folioCompleto= $row['folioCompleto'];
```

la funcion ultimofolio() esta asi

```
    public function ultimofolio(){
     $sql = "SELECT MAX(folio) AS total, pkorden_trabajo 
             FROM orden_trabajo";
     $datos = $this->conn->consultaRetorno($sql);
     return $datos;
     $this->conn->close();
    }
```

espero te sirva, saludos XD

Comment: Que tal bro, oye la conexión como la haces? eso solo es el PHP?

Comment: es con puro PHP